# Excel - Freezing a Calculated Date Until The Date Itself Has Passed

Tags: excel

Is it possible to have Excel freeze a calculated date until the calculated date itself has passed?

Within the Excel example below, *Today's Date* is formulated with TODAY(), and *Next Proposed Meeting* is a calculated date by adding Today's Date plus Meeting Cadence.

Excel Example:
[image]

Here is what I'm looking to do: when a user opens the workbook and sets the initial meeting cadence, I would like to freeze the *Next Proposed Meeting* date until that specific date meets the date referenced in today's date.

(Example: today's date is Monday, October 1, 2018 and the next proposed meeting date is Monday, October 1, 2018).

When the two dates match, I would like it to cycle to the next date, depending on the numerical value of the cadence. So, if the meeting cadence continued to be 7 days, the *Next Proposed Meeting* cell would automatically populate to "Monday, October 8, 2018."

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Cheers, and thank you!
:)

Comment: Are the meetings always on a Monday?

Comment: No, they can occur any day of the week.

Comment: And how does Excel "know" this?

Comment: Excel is just calculating out a formula based on Today's Date plus whatever Meeting Cadence is entered. The user can enter any number of days for the meeting cadence, and Excel will calculate it accordingly based off of today's date.... but today's date should remain fluid, as should the meeting cadence, but the next proposed meeting date should remain static.

Comment: Something about your question is breaking my brain.  I think it's that you are saying two mutually exclusive things: the formula should add 7 (or whatever the cadence is) to today's date, but that that number should stay the same until today is the same as that date.

Comment: The question was very hard to word, but you've got it!

Comment: It's kind of like a loop. You start at today's date, add whatever the meeting cadence is, and keep the proposed meeting date the same until the proposed meeting date is equal to today's date, then repeat!

Comment: You need a decision point to differentiate the two possible scenarios: 1) Take today's date and add the Meeting Cadence to generate a new meeting date 2) Ignore today's date and take the meeting date decided upon on a previous day.

Comment: I was hoping to do both, but it doesn't appear to be an option, at least via formulas... I wonder if it's doable via VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacked this out.
In a module:

```
Sub setCurrentProposedDate(cadenceChanged As Boolean)
    Dim currProposedDate As Name, currCadence As Name
    Set currProposedDate = ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("CurrentProposed")
    Set currCadence = ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("CurrentCadence")
    If cadenceChanged Then
        currProposedDate.Value = Sheet1.Range("B2").Value - Evaluate(currCadence.Value) + Evaluate(currProposedDate.Value)
        currCadence.Value = Sheet1.Range("B2").Value
    End If
    If Sheet1.Range("B1").Value - Evaluate(currProposedDate.Value) >= 0 Then
        currProposedDate.Value = Sheet1.Range("B2").Value + Evaluate(currProposedDate.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

In workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    setCurrentProposedDate False
End Sub
```

In Sheet1 module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        setCurrentProposedDate True
    End If
End Sub
```

Set workbook level names to be :

[image]

Put this formula in B3:
`=CurrentProposed`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stab at doing that via formula...
 - Set a Project Start Date such as Monday, 3 September, 2018 in B1
 - Enter your cadence value (7, 10, 14, etc.) in B2
 - Formula for "Next Meeting" in B3 is  `=SUM(B1,PRODUCT(ROUNDDOWN(DAYS(TODAY(),B1)/B2,0)+1,B2))`

Explanation:
 - The Rounded down value of the date difference between two dates (Start Date and Today) gives you a whole number indicating the number of periods (based on cadence) you are after the start
 - Add one to that b/c you want to predict the next meeting date 
 - Multiply that by the cadence to get the number of days until next meeting date (from the start)
 - Modify the cadence (B2) and your next meeting date should adjust appropriately.

I tested with my project and a few random dates and cadences and it seems to work.